# Is there a time limit on current easyJet's rebooking fees (0€)?

Tags: bookings, fees-and-charges, easyjet

EasyJet is not currently charging for rebooking fees due to the uncertainty with COVID-19. You still need to pay the fare difference.

This is in the case where the traveller who has a  valid ticket for a scheduled flight would like to change the flight on their own decision (the cost is normally 50€)

I tried to look for an announcement that would set end dates for this campaign but did not find anything. EasyJet's pages just use the word "currently".

**Is there an end-date for that zero rebooking fees campaign?**

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks for the unexpected lesson in English (details at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/259449/how-to-capitalize-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence-a-word-that-has-a-fixed-capital)

Comment: Unanswerable. Who knows what the EasyJet CEO decides tomorrow?? Btw, this is currently becoming standard in the industry, as nobody want's to be the bad guy; Southwest had it always.

Comment: @Aganju: it would be answerable if easyJet had announced it with some link to COVID-19 and governmental actions around it. This is the kind of announcement I was looking for (and did not find, so it will probably last until it does not anymore)